# Compile with NEON using arm-linux-gnueabihf

Tags: gcc, neon

I'm using a Cross compiler (arm-linux-gnueabihf) running in Eclipse in a VM under Debian 8.1. I'm having difficulty trying to use NEON intrinsics.
I have included arm_neon.h in the source code and use the following:

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.9 -I/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.2/include -O3 -march=armv7-a  -mtune=cortex-a8 -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -g3 -pg -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0

The code compiles and finds the arm_neon.h include but gives an error on the intrinsic int8x8_t a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
:33:15: error: expected expression before ‘[’ token

=== update ===
Changed test line to int8x8_t a = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
Even before I compile the Eclipse toolchain indicates
"int8x8_t can't be resolved"

I likewise have the two lines
    int8x8_t b = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    uint8x8_t c= vclt_s8(a,b);

The code compiles but warns c is an unused variable (true it is) but the Toolchain editor indicates both int8x8_t and uint8x8_t can't be resolved.

Comment: So... a C compiler chokes on invalid C syntax? `[]` is the array dereferencing operator, and you're not dereferencing an array, are you?

Comment: Opps! Thanks, I blindly copied some code that turned out to be pseudo code :}. I updated the problem (see above). My Toolchain in Eclipse still complains the vectorized variables can't be resolved, yet it compiles & links okay.

Comment: Well, I doubt the syntax parser built into the Eclipse CDT indexer has much support for intrinsics of any architecture, nor [entirely compiler-specific syntax extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions). You could possibly try to convince it to slurp some of the compiler-defined macros out of GCC to make it a bit cleverer at reading the headers, but that's an entirely different question... ;)